# CustomError not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate, custom-errors

I use ASP.NET Boilerplate  MVC template

In web.config I set

```
<customErrors mode="On"/>
```

but when an exception throw this response show in the browser

**Runtime Error**

**Description**: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.

**Details**: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".

Comment: Are you throwing exception in an AJAX method?

Comment: No, I throw an exception in simple action with action result return

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

in order to see development time errors.

When you set this to `On` it redirects you to error page which is specified in web.config which you can customize on the basis of statusCode received. Say `404` statusCode will redirect to `NotFound` method of `ErrorController`

As below

```
   <customErrors mode="On"
      defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: My problem is that the error page is not redirected

Comment: @Miki, Have you setup `defaultRedirect`?

Comment: No, but I think asp.net boilerplate do it

Comment: According to the Asp.net boilerplate Documentation and considering, Error.cshtml code have error model and process it, I think boilerplate have a controller that when error accord, redirect to it.
but I can not found it